# Flutter Main thread performance

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, listview

## Cannot optimise UI with 20,000+ items.

In Screen A; from API response I'm getting JSON file URL of products list (20,000+ items). After receiving JSON file URL, for background process I have used Isolates and compute and I'm making changes in its model and passing it to Screen B.

In Screen B I'm simple using Listview.builder (As I know it is optimised to display items as we scroll). And **my requirement is to display all 20,000+ items all at once on UI**. And I'm performing sortBy and filterBy.

Due to this, my UI gets very laggy and sometimes not responsive. I tried for Isolates and compute to optimise my UI rendering. But I got no success.

Can anyone share their experience on how to resolve or any reference, that would be helpful. Thanks

For reference: Flutter Channel stable, 3.10.6 Dart SDK 3.0.6

Comment: You've got to push most of this to server side.  Your phone is not powerful enough to deal with the semantic meaning of 20,000 objects like that.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz is right, it's hard to deal with these many objects.  From my own experience, I faced something similar to this (48000+ objects with randomized operation). To overcome this issue I chose pagination from the server side. and from the app, it loads more objects when It reaches the end of the list builder.

Comment: Agree with @RandalSchwartz

Comment: Can you share a sample Widget that you're rendering inside Listview?

Comment: can you post relevant code

Comment: I cannot use pagination, as I have to do functionality on received items.

Comment: Hello and I cannot use stateless widget, as data of my list item will get updated, that is pricing of each product will get updated every second. 

So every second I have to do sorting based on updated price. 

Please correct me if I'm wrong, that I cannot use stateless widgets.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a simple application that fetches data from local JSON that has nearly 20,000 objects. It uses `compute` to decode JSON and ListView.builder to dynamically render each item as the UI is scrolled. Using a cubit to store List of items and to do the filtering. The app was rock-stable without any lags or issues. You can check the whole source code [here](https://github.com/soliev01/icondemo).

```
class PersonList extends StatelessWidget {
  const PersonList({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<PersonCubit, List<Person>>(
      builder: (context, items) {
        if (items.isEmpty) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
        return ListView.builder(
          prototypeItem: PersonTile(Person.dummy()),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            return PersonTile(items[index]);
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

```
class PersonTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const PersonTile(this.p, {super.key});
  final Person p;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final id = p.id;
    final color = int.parse('0xFF${id.substring(id.length - 5, id.length)}');
    return Card(
      elevation: 0,
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(p.name),
        subtitle: _Info(balance: p.balance, email: p.email, date: p.registered),
        trailing: Icon(
          Icons.circle,
          color: p.isActive ? Colors.greenAccent : Colors.red,
        ),
        isThreeLine: true,
        tileColor: Color(color),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailScreen(p: p)));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class PersonCubit extends Cubit<List<Person>> {
  PersonCubit() : super(const []);

  void fetchItems() async {
    try {
      final s = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data.json');
      final items = await compute(parseItems, s);
      emit(items);
    } catch (e, st) {
      // log
      log('Error fetching data!', error: e, stackTrace: st);
      emit(const []);
    }
  }

  void sortByDate() {
    emit(state.toList()..sort((a, b) => a.registered.compareTo(b.registered)));
  }

  void sortByName() {
    emit(state.toList()..sort((a, b) => a.name.compareTo(b.name)));
  }

  void sortByBalance() {
    emit(state.toList()..sort((a, b) => a.balance.compareTo(b.balance)));
  }
}
```

Comment: I did the same thing. But, the issue is whenever you put the Scrollbar widget on the top of the ListView builder widget & scroll the list using that Scrollbar widget, at that moment, the whole app will start lagging & it becomes unstable.

Comment: So, you can't jump from 1 to 10,000 without lagging & it will fall for sure.

Comment: No, you're wrong about jumping to 10,000. It does it without any problem. You are not aware of how `ListView.builder` works if you think so. Check out the repository where I added jump to middle button to test your take.

Comment: Hello @Soliev, let me check repository. Coz even I'm able to display list at a time.. but when I do scrolling it lags and feels like glitchy.

Comment: Hello @Soliev and I cannot use stateless widget, as data of my list item will get updated, that is pricing of each product will get updated every second. 

So every second I have to do sorting based on updated price.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, that I cannot use stateless widgets.

Comment: So you're telling me you call an API every second and show 20,000 Items in a ListView?

Comment: Hello @Soliev 
No, data I will get from Screen A (20,000 items), then data will be navigate to Screen B.

Now on Screen B, there are some fields (pricing) that will update on every second. and the list will be update on price sorting.

So yes stateless widget I think it won't work. as listview is getting updated frequently, with updated params and sorting.

Comment: How is the pricing updated every second? you need to make an API call right?

Comment: Hello @Soliev it's a scanning module so whatever barcode tags is been read, it will automatically updated in the list with meta data..

Comment: If you use any state management library you can avoid stateful widgets. You can handle sorting all items with updated fields and then rerender the UI visible on the screen. It's hard to come up with a useful solution without seeing your implementations.